# IoT hub and device provisioning service

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

Is Microsoft provided few standard device provisioning service in Azure marketplace which can be directly used for device provisioning for any custom device? Or OEM needs to create a device provisioning service for their custom device ,put that in the market place and then use that device provisioning service from market place?

Could someone please clarify? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

MS has a Auto-provisioning service but is not a full fledged system. But that is to be expected as the market requirements can be vary broad and very much use case specific.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/

In terms of OEM services. OEM's can probably create such services, but again the use case and ownership questions arise.

So the basically the 'basic' tools are there but it is kinda left to you on how you want to deal with the situation. Thinking of integration with CI/CD and the custom software needed to install on each device - Some custom work such a provisioning service is need. At least in our case.

But this can be a nightmare when going to the thousands of devices to manage.

Answer (score 0):

As Van mentioned, Azure does have a device provisioning service that can be used for any custom device, and [new features](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/happy-anniversary-new-iot-hub-device-provisioning-service-features-out-today/) were announced about a month ago.

If there are gaps in the service, please suggest improvements in the [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/321918-azure-iot/)! As the PM for provisioning service, knowing the gaps means we can start to fill them.